# VKSdk - получение и обработка сообщений

Tags: java, android, алгоритм, vkontakte-api

Добрый день. Делаю тут одну программу, с использованием VKSdk. Проблем с отправкой запросов у меня не было, но как только дошло дело до получения данных с серверов ВК, то сразу возникло много вопросов. Я долго копался в интернете, но так и не нашёл толковых примеров с обработкой новых сообщений.

Алгоритм должен быть такой: при получении новых сообщений, программа, к примеру, отправляет тому же человеку данные о сообщении (id отправителя, его сообщение и время).
И вот у меня возникают следующие вопросы:

1) Есть ли какой-нибудь метод в sdk, который будет выполняться при получении новых сообщений? Или нужно вручную проверять?

2) Как обработать полученные данные?

Заранее спасибо! :)

Comment: метод работы есть... непосредственно у АПИ описывается в доках https://vk.com/dev/using_longpoll

Comment: Там всё описано, как это должно работать в теории, а вот хотелось бы увидеть реальный код. Жаль, что в документации к android там ничего толком и не говорят...